# Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'

Tags: javascript, object

Is it problematic to reference an object literal within a function which is part of that very literal? It seems to work just fine, but I want to make sure there aren't other implications.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

instead of:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){return this.key1 + " works!"}
};
alert(obj.key2());
```

using:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){return obj.key1 + " works!"}
};
alert(obj.key2());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both can be problematic.

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){ return this.key1 + " works!" }
};
var func = obj.key2;
alert(func()); // error
```

When `func` is not called as a method of `obj`, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) can reference something else (in here: the global object "`window`").

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){ return obj.key1 + " works!" }
};
var newref = obj;
obj = { key1: "something else"; };
alert(newref.key2()); // "something else works"
```

In here we access the object from another reference, though the `obj` in the function may now point to some other object.

So you will have to choose which case is more likely. If you really want to make it safe, prevent `obj` from being exchanged:

```
// ES6 - use `const`:
const obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){ return obj.key1 + " works always!" }
};

// ES5: use a closure where the `obj` is stored in a local-scoped variable:
var obj = (function(){
    var local = {
        key1: "it",
        key2: function(){ return local.key1 + " works always!" }
    };
    return local;
})();
```

or you [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to the object:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){ return this.key1 + " works always!" }
}
obj.key2 = obj.key2.bind(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be a difference in variable scope binding.  If you modify obj later, you will modify the return value of key2:

```
var newobj = obj;
obj = { key1: "new" };
alert(newobj.key2());
```

Now it alerts "new works!", because even though you are calling `key2()` on the original object (which is now `newobj`), the reference to `obj.key1` now binds to the value of the new `obj` instance.  Using `this` prevents this from happening.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m6CU3/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using prototype object, you czn go like that. as all instances of your object will return the value of the obj instance...

Answer (score 1):

Either or both of those techniques may apply depending on the situation.

The value of `this` within a function depends on how the function was called. If you call a function as property of an object like this:

```
obj.key2();
//or
obj["key2"]();
```

Then `this` will be that object. Whether the object was created via an object literal or some other means is not relevant.

But you can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or `.apply()` to call a function and explicitly set `this` to some other object.

Consider also:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: function(){return this.key1 + " works!"}
};
alert(obj.key2()); // alerts "it works!"

var func = obj.key2;
alert(func())​;     // alerts "undefined works!"
```

I'm setting up `func` to reference the same function as `obj.key2`, but calling it as `func()` does *not* set `this` to `obj`.

For more information have a look at [what MDN has to say about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any implications off the top of my head. Just make sure you don't accidentally do this at any point:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "it",
    key2: key1 + " works!"
}
```

As that will cause an error. Other than that, you should be good to go!