# Accessing parent of a parent object properties

Tags: javascript

if i have :

```
var obj= {
    a:"something", 
    b:{ 
        a:function (){
        // Can I access obj properties through the this keyword here
        }
    }
};
```

Can I access properties of `obj` through the `this` keyword in the `obj.b.a` function?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `this` instead of `obj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: There could be many properties on many objects pointing to the object. Which one would be the parent? Also, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) how the `this` keyword really works: It only points to the `obj.b` object when your function is called with `obj.b.a()`.

However, you can still use the `obj` variable as a reference. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711164/1048572) I have discussed the differences to `this`.

Comment: your `__parent__` link is unrelated, albeit interesting.