# Why can't I reference a variable within a custom object?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I'm just picking up Javascript, and I don't understand this problem.

I have created a custom object called `DeleteReasonCodes` with an instance variable called `delReasonCodes`, declared as an array.  However, the inner methods can't seem to see this instance variable.  Every time I try to run it, I get a `delReasonCodes is not defined` error.

Perhaps I'm just not understanding the Javascript scoping rules?

```
var DeleteReasonCodes = {

    delReasonCodes: [],

    get: function ()
    {
        return delReasonCodes;
    },

    add: function (code, desc)
    {
        delReasonCodes.push(new DeleteReasonCode(code, desc));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, javascript scoping belongs to functions (and nothing else).

The only variable you have created is `DeleteReasonCodes`, and you have assigned it an object with 3 *properties*. You can access them via a [property accessor operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) if you have a reference to the object. In your case, you could use `this.delReasonCode` or `DeleteReasonCodes.delReasonCode` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711164/1048572) for the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're treating a JavaScript object as you would a class in another language.  Local-scope in JavaScript only resides inside functions, not objects.  In your case, you need to access the data with a fully-qualified name:

```
DeleteReasonCodes.delReasonCodes.push();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this

```
delReasonCodes: [],

get: function() {
    return this.delReasonCodes;
},
```