# How do I reference property from method of the same object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, reference

Could you tell me why this will not work? (note the **this** keyword)

```
var post = {
    url: 'http://myurl.com',
    add: function() {
        window.location = this.url + '/add';
    },
    edit: function() {
        window.location = this.url + '/edit';
    }
};
```

Somewhere else in the code:

```
post.url = '<?php echo BASE_ADMIN . $postType ?>';

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#listing").aJqueryPlugin({
    ...
    // Buttons and their callbacks
    buttons : [
        {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : post.add},
        {name: 'Edit', bclass: 'edit', onpress : post.edit},
    ],
   ...
});
```

The line

post.url = ....

behaves as expected. The **url** property in **post** is updated.

However, when I click on the **Add** or **Edit** buttons, and I enter their functions, **this.url** is **undefined** because **this** references the button instead of the **post** object. Why? What should I do then to reference the **url** property from a callback?

Comment: See "closures" or `Function.bind`.

Comment: This is not related to closures, but execution context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/).

```
    {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : $.proxy(post, "add")},
    {name: 'Edit', bclass: 'edit', onpress : $.proxy(post, "edit")},
```

This returns a new function that will call the method of the object named by the string.

---

It's effectively doing this:

```
{name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : function() {
                                           return post["add"].apply(post, arguments);
                                       },
{name: 'Edit', bclass: 'edit', onpress : function() {
                                           return post["edit"].apply(post, arguments);
                                         },
```

---

Because the value of `this` in a function is dependent on how the function was called, you sometimes need alternate means to ensure that you get the correct value.

---

You could also set these in your original object, as long as you know you always want `this` to refer to that object.

```
var post = {
    url: 'http://myurl.com'
};
post.add = $.proxy(function() {
    window.location = this.url + '/add';
}, post);
post.edit = $.proxy(function() {
    window.location = this.url + '/edit';
}, post);
```

This uses the other signature of `$.proxy`, which lets you pass the function directly followed by the desired `this` value.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! This works after a little adjustment, because **this** inside the "add" and "edit" functions now references **Window**. So I had to change 
this.url + "/add" 
for 
post.url + "/add".

Comment: @LuisMartin: It references `window` after using `$.proxy`? It shouldn't.

Comment: I can't grasp why this happens in callbacks. Referencing **this** externally works however: this.url = 'whatever';

Comment: @LuisMartin: The value of `this` depends on how the function was called. If you do `post.add()`, the value of `this` in `add` will be automatically set to `post`. But if you *pass* `post.add` to another function, you're only passing the method, not the object, so it forgets where it came from. Using `$.proxy` returns a new function that uses the `post` object to invoke the `"add"` method so that its `this` value is retained.

Comment: @user1689607: It really references **Window** inside the function. In fact changing **this** for **post** works.

Comment: @LuisMartin: Yes, changing `this` to `post` will clearly work because you're referencing the `post` object explicitly instead of hoping `this` will reference it. But if you did `onpress: $.proxy(post, "add")`, then `this` in the `add` method will refer to the `post` object. If it doesn't, then you did something wrong.

Comment: yes I did it wrong, sorry. I was doing $.proxy(post.add) instead of $.proxy(post, "add") Now it works. I appreciate a lot your help!