# Javascript object literal & "this" context?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key’s function instead of ‘this’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this)

I have this simple code :

```
var myObj = {
    init: function ()
    {
        this.Name = "Royi";
        this.BindMe();
    }
    BindMe: function ()
    {
        $('myButton').on("click", this.Work);
    },
    Work: function ()
    {
        var self = this; <--------
    }
}
```

Running :

```
myObj.init();
```

This is a simple Object literal.
The problem is on the `Work` Method. I want to make it know `this` ( `myObj`)

there are 2 ways of doing it :

**option #1**

In `BindMe` , When clicking , transfer the context via :

`$('myButton').on("click",{self:this}, this.Work);`

and in `Work` do :

`var self = e.data.self...` //need also to add `e`

**option #2**

write `var self = myObj ;`

**Question**

- Is there any other way  of doing it ?
- which is the better/correct way ?

Comment: Is not using an object literal an option?

Comment: @Bergi I already saw this question. it doesnt provide the answer. ( to my specific question).

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker No. I want to learn this behavior in literal object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add it as data to the event object. Instead, use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or the jQuery-ish (crossbrowser) [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to provide the correct thisArg to the function (see MDN's [introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)):

```
$('myButton').on("click", $.proxy(this, "Work"));
```

Comment: What's the difference between `$.proxy` and `Function#bind`?

Comment: It seems to me that `$.proxy(f,t)` is the same as `f.bind(t)`. Am I right?

Comment: nice solution. ( p.s. this answer wasnt on the duplicated question FYI). But Again , regarding my second option , is it ok to do so?

Comment: @JanDvorak http://jsfiddle.net/sERVx/12/

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yeah, sure, but why bind it to a local variable `self` at all if you want to statically refer to `myObj`? Have a look at [the possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) on whether it's a good solution.

Comment: @RoyiNamir misunderstood what you meant by option #2, sorry

Comment: @Bergi can you please go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20459/room-for-royi-namir-and-bergi ?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the context to the handler function as part of a closure:

```
$('myButton').on("click", (function(context) {
    return function() {
        context.Work
    };
})(this));
```

Needless to say, this is cross browser, since it relies on one of the core features of JS.