# Setting JavaScript "class" properties from internal function using "this" Keyword?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, revealing-module-pattern

I am surprised that I could not find more on this topic (could be my sub-par search skills). Typically once I think I understand how the JavaScript keyword, "this" works it then stops working the way I understand. I'll address one such issue.

My understanding: "When a function is called using the 'new' keyword ... 'this' refers to the root function/'class'. When used from functions within the instantiated 'class' this refers to the CALLING function". -- This is very important to understand: when the function is called from another function on the page the 'this' keyword will refer calling function and not the 'class' within which the target function lives.

In the following example I have tried two ways to set a variable from a public function. Both fail. I am attempting to understand why this is and how to make this work.

```
var functionClass = new function(){

    var _isReady = false;

    var _getReady = function(){
        // ... do some work to get ready
        _isReady = true;
    }

    return {

        IsReady: _isReady,
        GetReady: _getReady
    }
}



var functionClass1 = new function () {

    var _isReady = false;
    var _self = this;

    var _getReady = function () {
        // ... do some work to get ready
        _self.IsReady = true;
    }

    return {

        IsReady: _isReady,
        GetReady: _getReady
    }
}


functionClass.GetReady();
functionClass1.GetReady();

console.log(functionClass.IsReady);  // Expect true ... I get false
console.log(functionClass1.IsReady); // Expect true ... I get false
```

**UPDATE**:

I Probably should point out that I am using the Revealing Module Pattern and would prefer that any solution be in that context. While I am sure there are a multitude of different ways of doing this I would like to focus the solution to this pattern.

Comment: if called without new keyword, then this refers to global object if not called this way: fn.call(ob, param) or fn.apply(ob, params)

Comment: But the functionClass and functionClass1 ARE instantiated using the 'new' keyword  -- new functionClass1 = new function (){ ... } .

Comment: Then there is no need for return statement. do this way: `_self.IsReady = _isReady; _self.GetReady = _getReady;`

Comment: I typically use the Revealing Module Pattern which exposes public methods and properties via an anonymous object. For me I prefer being able to define and use private members, and it keeps the public interface clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a function is called using the 'new' keyword ... 'this' refers to the root function/'class'

No. It refers to a newly instantiated object that inherits from the object on the constructor functions' `prototype` property. This object will be the result of the `new`-expression if none was explicitly returned from the function.

> When used from functions within the instantiated 'class' this refers to the CALLING function"

No. It usually refers to the instance.

> When the function is called from another function on the page the 'this' keyword will refer calling function and not the 'class' within which the target function lives

No. Again, it usually refers to the instance. Though it always depends on how the function is called - read [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

And in your case, a module creation, you should not use `new` at all. There is no inheritance involved anywhere. Change it to an immediately-executed function expression (IEFE, you can search for that).

So why do your two attempts fail now?

The `functionClass` gets assigned an object which has two properties: `GetReady` which is set to the `_getReady` function, and `IsReady` which is set to value of `_isReady`, i.e. `false`. Yet, when you call the method, it will only change the `_isReady` variable, not the `IsReady` property of `functionClass`.

In `functionClass1` you are correctly assigning to a property. But of what? `_self` is the `this` value from the module function that was abused as a constructor, and as explained above that's an object inheriting from another object (whose `.constructor` is the anonymous function used for the module). It is not - as you seem to have expected - the `functionClass1` object which you did `return`.

So how do you refer to that object correctly? Well, the simplest choice is to use its variable name. Another choice is to use `this` in the getReady function, which will refer to the object if it called with `functionClass.GetReady()`. See [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) for pros and cons.

```
var functionClass = {
    IsReady: false,
    GetReady: function(){
        // ... do some work to get ready
        this.IsReady = true;
    }
};
functionClass.GetReady();
console.log(functionClass.IsReady);  // true now
```

Comment: Your example was an object literal where I prefer to use the Revealing Module Pattern, but combined with your explanation you got me where I needed to go, so thank you very much! Although, now I am confused about the proper use of "new" ... LOL

Comment: In the linked question [there is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10711164/1048572) some kind of revealing module pattern (the example with the `local` variable). The [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is only to be used if you need a) a constructor ("init function") *and* b) inheritance from a common prototype

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if this is what you need

```
 var functionClass = (function(){

        var _isReady = false;

        var _getReady = function(){
            // ... do some work to get ready
            _isReady = true;
        }

        return {

            IsReady: _isReady,
            GetReady: _getReady
        }
    })();
```

Comment: This produced the same results. I put it into a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gary_stenstrom/5yRws/)

Comment: Actually discovered that this works but ... in the _getReady() method definition the new value must be assigned to "this.IsReady" (property) rather than "_isReady" (variable). I'm upvoting this post for heading me in the right direction! Thank you!