# Accessing an object inside another object

Tags: javascript

Hi I am getting an uncaught reference exception on my code.This is what I have:

```
 var config = {
    debug: true,
    data: {
        debug: false,
        logErrorsOnServer: true,
        defaultCulture: '',
        serviceUrl: ''
    },

    init: function(options) {
        if (!options) {
            return;
        }          
        if (options.hasOwnProperty('debug')) {
            data.debug = options.debug;
        }

    },
};
```

When I try to get the value of data.debug I get an uncaught reference error that says:

```
UncoughtReference Error: data is not defined
```

Whay can't I acces my data object?

Comment: Could be wrong here but try this.data.debug

Comment: What is going wrong. At a first glance everything okay in Chrome devtools

Comment: data.debug = options.debug throws UncoughtReference Error: data is not defined

Comment: I don't get it. You have config.debug, data.debug and options.hasOwnProperty('debug'). In my view, that's two to many.

Comment: Well, you have no variable `data` as far as I can see. If you want to to access the `data` property of the `config` object, you have to use `config.data` or `this.data`, assuming you call the function with `config.init()`. JavaScript doesn't have any hidden magic like Java where `this.` is implicit (and that's a good thing). It does exactly what you tell it to do (most of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say:

```
this.data.debug = options.debug;
```

...assuming that you are calling the `init()` function in a way that sets [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the (outer) object, e.g., with `config.init()`.

Or you can say:

```
config.data.debug = options.debug;
```

The reason you got an error about `data` not being defined when you tried to use `data.debug` directly is that in fact `data` is *not* defined as a variable, it is a property of the object. Just because `init()` is a method on your object doesn't mean it automatically references other object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `data` **variable** *is* undefined. You probably want to use the object on your `.data` **property** of `config` (accessible via the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)):

```
…
    if (options.hasOwnProperty('debug')) {
        this.data.debug = options.debug;
    }
…
```

See also [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) for different methods to access `.data`.