# what's wrong with my code in creating a method in object literal notation?

Tags: javascript

I have asked a question about [creating a method in object literal notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486854/how-to-create-a-method-in-object-literal-notation?noredirect=1#comment25415414_17486854) half hour ago. I got good answers, but something is still wrong with my code. I was told to create a new question and here it is. Please don't judge the code by the efficiency. I know that I have used many bio method three times in each object, when I could do 1 function, but I did it to understand more about objects,functions and methods.

So here is my code.

```
var object1 = new Object()
object1.name = "Neymar";
object1.age = 22;
object1.club = "Barca";
object1.bio = function (){
    console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
};
var object2 = {
name: "Fred",
age: 28,
club: "Fluminense"
bio2: function (){
    console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
    };
};
var object3 = {
name: "Hulk",
age: 27,
club: "Zenit St. Petersburg"
bio3: function (){
    console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
    };
};
object1.bio();
object2.bio2();
object3.bio3();
```

The CodeAcademy say's that } is missing on the 12th line: bio2: function (){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your object should look like this,

```
var object2 = {
   name: "Fred",
   age: 28,
   club: "Fluminense",
   bio2: function (){
      console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
   }
};
```

You don't ever have semi-colons in js object's - where you had it anyway, and you shouldn't have a comma on the last item in the object either - it breaks in IE

you also forgot the comma on the line before the `function`

Quick tip. when debugging javascript the errors could be caused from the line above i recommend going to http://jsfiddle.net and using the jsHint tool that's built in

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put a comma after the previous property, so it considered it to be the end of the literal. Maybe `expected ',' or '}'` would've been a better message. Also, inside the object literal you're not allowed to put a line delimiter (semicolon). It should be

```
var object2 = {
    name: "Fred",
    age: 28,
    club: "Fluminense",
//                    ^
    bio2: function() {
        console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
    }
//   ^
};
var object3 = {
    name: "Hulk",
    age: 27,
    club: "Zenit St. Petersburg",
//                              ^
    bio3: function() {
        console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
    }
//   ^
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `,` after `club: "Fluminense"` and `club: "Zenit St. Petersburg"`

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a common (`,`) after `club: "Fluminense"` and `club: "Zenit St. Petersburg"`. You must also remove the end of line delimiter (`;`) from the ends of your object parameters.

```
var object2 = {
    name: "Fred",
    age: 28,
    club: "Fluminense",
    bio2: function (){
    console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
}

};
var object3 = {
    name: "Hulk",
    age: 27,
    club: "Zenit St. Petersburg",
    bio3: function (){
    console.log(this.name +" is "+ this.age + " years old and he is playing in "+ this.club);
}
```