# Typescript cant access object property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have little issue accessing object property in typscript. this works fine in js but doesn't in ts

```
let getUserName = {
    firstname : "timi",
    lastname: "oluwayomi",
    middlename: "ola",
    full : () => { return this.firstname + this.lastname + this.middlename } ,
    first: () => {  return this.firstname }
  }
console.log(getUserName.first())
```

in javascript output: timi
but ts throws error. is there a different way to access it in ts ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a method in object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486854/how-to-create-a-method-in-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just refer to the same object in the object, this is a hack IMO

```js
let getUserName = {
    firstname : "timi",
    lastname: "oluwayomi",
    middlename: "ola",
    full : () => { return getUserName.firstname + getUserName.lastname + getUserName.middlename } ,
    first: () => {  return getUserName.firstname }
  }
console.log(getUserName.first())
```

Comment: yeah thanks , worked but one thing left initialization error, but already solved

Answer (score 1):

this inside arrow function refers to the global object, so its giving error, you can try with traditional functions

```
 let getUserName = {
    firstname : "timi",
    lastname: "oluwayomi",
    middlename: "ola",
    full : function() { return this.firstname + this.lastname + this.middlename } ,
    first: function() {  return this.firstname }
  }
console.log(getUserName.first())
```

Answer (score 1):

i was working on an component based project "Angular"
so i had to initialize first

```
getUserName : any;

getUserName = {
    firstname : "timi",
    lastname: "oluwayomi",
    middlename: "ola",
    full : () => { return getUserName.firstname + getUserName.lastname + getUserName.middlename } ,
    first: () => {  return getUserName.firstname }
  }
console.log(getUserName.first())
```

also thanks to Dean Van Greunen

Comment: If your question is resolved, please mark one of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `this` within an arrow function. Inside an arrow function, `this` refers to the global object, not the execution context. See [You Don't Know JS Yet - Chapter 3 - `this` Keyword](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/get-started/ch3.md#this-keyword) for more info on `this`.
So, to start with, use this:

```
let getUserName = {
  firstname : "timi",
  lastname: "oluwayomi",
  middlename: "ola",
  full() { return this.firstname + this.lastname + this.middlename },
  first() {  return this.firstname },
}
```

As `this` is of type `any` in this case, as the TypeScript compiler cannot infer the type of your object for you, you will need to type the object yourself (usually a good idea anyway):

```
type GetUserName = {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  middlename: string;
  full(): string;
  first(): string;
}

let getUserName: GetUserName = {
  firstname: "timi",
  lastname: "oluwayomi",
  middlename: "ola",
  full(this: GetUserName) {
    return this.firstname + this.lastname + this.middlename;
  },
  first(this: GetUserName) {
    return this.firstname;
  },
};
```