# Javascript scope and variables

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

```
var name = "Bob";

var book = {
    name: "Harry Potter",
    writeName: function() {
        return function() {
            document.writeln(this.book.name);
        }
    }
};
```

When I call this

```
book.writeName()();
```

I want it to print *Harry Potter* (not *Bob*) which it does above, however this:

```
var book2 = book;
book = null;
book2.writeName()();
```

Now looks for `this.book` (which is `null`) where it should be looking for `this.book2`

How can I reference the variable?

Comment: Don't use `this`.

Comment: @Bergi But when I change to book2 it still looks for book

Comment: OK sorry I have to refine: Don't use `this` where inappropriate, like here inside the returned function where [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the global object :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need here is a variable in the `writeName` closure:

```
var book = {
    name: "Harry Potter",
    writeName: function() {
        var name = this.name; // turn dynamic property into closure variable
        return function() {
            document.writeln(name);
        }
    }
};
book.writeName()(); // Harry Potter
```

Instead of storing only the `name` in the closure, you also could store a reference to the object like in @Quentin's answer. It might make a difference if you plan to change the `.name` property before calling the returned function.

For the question whether to use `this` or `book` for referencing your object see [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are returning a function, you are going to lose whatever context you got from calling the function that generates it.

You need that context to reference the object, so you need to preserve it.

```
writeName: function() {
    var myBook = this;
```

You then need to use that preserved context:

```
    return function() {
        document.writeln(myBook.name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :  http://jsbin.com/pagumiwi/4/edit

```
var name = "Bob";

var book = {
    name: "Harry Potter",
    writeName: function() {
        return function() {
            document.writeln(this.name);
        }
      }()
    };



book.writeName(); //would also work
var book2 = book;
book = null;
book2.writeName(); //would also work
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't want to change the way I call the functions so I still want to call book.writeName()();

Comment: @CamSonaris You should have mention this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` changes when the context changes you need to save a reference to the original `this`. Here I've used `_this`

```
var book = {
  name: "Harry Potter",
  writeName: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return function() {
      console.log(_this.name);
    }
  }
};

book.writeName()() //  Harry Potter

var book2 = book;
book = null;
book2.writeName()();  //  Harry Potter
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KWLXn/6/)