# Using object variable within function. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have recently started to learn JavaScript and would like to know if it is possible to use a object variable in a function directly within the same object. Here is my code so far.

```
    var user = {
    name: 'Example',
    age: 687,
    address: {
    firstLine: '20',
    secondLine: 'St Fake',
    thirdLine: 'Fakeland'   
    },
    logName: function(inputName, inputAge){
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(user.age);
    console.log(inputAge);
    console.log(inputName);
    }
    };

    user.logName('Richard', 20);
```

How is it possible to link to the name and age variables of user in the function without needing to prefix the object name onto the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this), you can just use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to get the object on which your function was called as a method upon. In your example:

```
var user = {
    name: 'Example',
    age: 687,
    address: {
        firstLine: '20',
        secondLine: 'St Fake',
        thirdLine: 'Fakeland'   
    },
    logName: function(inputName, inputAge) {
        console.log(this.name);
//                  ^^^^
        console.log(this.age);
//                  ^^^^
        console.log(inputAge);
        console.log(inputName);
    }
};

user.logName('Richard', 20); // method call on `user`,
                             // so `this` will become the `user` in the function
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the "this" key word!

Just reference it by this.value

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `this` keyword . You can better understand `this` keyword using [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fully-understanding-the-codethiscode-keyword--net-21117)

The code will be  like this

```
var user = {
    name: 'Example',
    age: 687,
    address: {
        firstLine: '20',
        secondLine: 'St Fake',
        thirdLine: 'Fakeland'
    },
    logName: function (inputName, inputAge) {
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.age);
        console.log(inputAge);
        console.log(inputName);
    }
};

user.logName('Richard', 20);
```