# How to correctly reference an method set on an object when declaring a method on this object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming

Kind of basic I guess. I'm writing on a modular application and am often running into having to do something like this:

```
var foo = {};

foo.do_something = function () {
  //...
};

foo.do_something_else = function () {
  // ...
};

foo.do_all = function () {
  var x = foo.do_something();

  // ...
};
```

I prefer to stick with functional programming like this.

**Question:**
Is it safe to reference methods declared on `foo` inside the declaration of other methods? Any better idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on [whether you use `this` or `foo`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) to refer to your object. If the object is an "instance" and has "methods" though, that is not very functional - better see `foo` as a namespace for your functions (and use it as such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fine.

You can also use `this` keyword, that refers to the specific instance. Be careful with `this`, because during execution the scope can change (because for example you invoke a method of an other object...).

To avoid it a good practice is to set in the first row of the method the assignment `var self=this` and then you can always use self for referencing the object instance.

Comment: Scope does not change. The `this` *context* does.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the module approach to accomplish the same separation of functionality, but without having to worry about constantly referencing a global name.

```
var foo = (function() {
  var do_something = function () {
    //...
  };

  var do_something_else = function () {
    // ...
  };

  var do_all = function () {
    // Note: can refer to `do_something` directly.
    var x = do_something();

    // ...
  };
  return {
      do_something: do_something,
      do_something_else: do_something_else,
      do_all: do_all
  };
})();
```

In general, you can use an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) to create a local, private scope in which you can define whatever you need to without having to worry about polluting global scope, and export functions or objects from within as needed.