# This vs Defining Object in Function Argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Below you will find two different decorator patterns. One uses "this" while the other one defines the object in the function arguments.

What is the advantage of defining the object vs using "this" from a memory/performance perspective? 
When is it appropriate to use this rather then defining the object?

```
//Using this in the object
    var carlike = function(loc) {
                this.loc = loc;
                var move = function() {
                    this.loc++;
                };
                this.move = move;
                return this;
            };

//Defining the object in the arguments
    var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
                obj.loc = loc;
                var move = function(obj) {
                    obj.loc++;
                };
                obj.move = move;
                return obj;
            };
```

Comment: Since `carlike` isn't a method, you need something like `carlike.call(obj, loc)` to set the value of `this`. Then, `carlike(obj, loc)` is probably a better approach in this case.

Comment: In the first one, where it says `obj.move = move;` is that supposed to be `this` instead of `obj`?

Comment: @Pointy, you are right. I made the edit.

Comment: Should `return obj` in the first one be `return this`?

Comment: @Barmar, I believe you are right. Made the correction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `carlike` function, there is no performance difference. However, as you say it is a decorator - which would be called as a static function on an object - not a constructor or method. You would want to use `carlike({}, 0)` instead of `carlike.call({}, 0)`, so go with the second pattern.

---

For the `move` function, there is a memory difference. The pattern with `obj` creates a closure, which costs more than the `this` in the first pattern. Which one to choose [is a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572), as they simply act different.

If you would want to optimize memory consumption, you could further improve the first pattern by not creating new `move` functions on every invocation of `carlike`. Just do

```
function move() {
    this.loc++;
}
function carlike(obj, loc) {
    obj.loc = loc;
    obj.move = move;
    return obj;
}
```