# referencing object property from multiple methods that act as eventhandlers

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm redisigning an old script, making it OOP first and then later use jQuery for it. I know this question is asked before, but the answers don't seem to fit in my situation. Or I don't get it without jQuery knowledge.

This working script resizes a DIV based on mousevents, that pass a boolean property between them. But the methods reference properties by object name which is bad OOP I understand.
I see a lot of answers with a "init" function and renaming "this" that I understand, but I can't relate those solutions to my script:

[See my Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/oysterhoys/6Lruvrbc/1/)

```
PositionXY = {
    baseX : undefined,
    baseY : undefined,
    isRepositionable : true,

    detectBasePosition : function (e) {

        "use strict";
        PositionXY.isRepositionable = true;   // bad OOP
        e = e || window.event;    // crossbrowser event acces
        if (this.currentStyle){   // IE
            if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
                PositionXY.baseX = e.clientX - this.currentStyle.width.replace(/px/,"");
                PositionXY.baseY = e.clientY - this.currentStyle.height.replace(/px/,"");   
            }
        } else if (window.getComputedStyle){  // Mozilla
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
                PositionXY.baseX = e.pageX - document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue("width").replace(/px/,"");
                PositionXY.baseY = e.pageY - document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue("height").replace(/px/,"");
            }
        }
    },
    startPositionAdjustment : function (e) {

        "use strict";
        if (PositionXY.isRepositionable) {   // bad OOP
            e = e || window.event;           // crossbrowser event acces
            if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {    // IE
                this.style.width = e.clientX - PositionXY.baseX + "px";
                this.style.height = e.clientY - PositionXY.baseY + "px";
            } else if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {  // Mozilla 
                this.style.width = e.pageX - PositionXY.baseX + "px";
                this.style.height  = e.pageY - PositionXY.baseY + "px";
            }
        } else return;
    },
    stopPositionAdjustment : function () {

        "use strict";
        PositionXY.isRepositionable = false;    // bad OOP
    }
};


var elm = document.getElementById("x");
elm.onmousedown = PositionXY.detectBasePosition;
elm.onmousemove = PositionXY.startPositionAdjustment;
elm.onmouseup = PositionXY.stopPositionAdjustment;
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question

Comment: No, it's not bad OOP. At least if you don't need multiple instances of your object. [It's even kinda required for your code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572), using `this` would be an unnecessary hazzle.

Comment: Sorry, could be more clear. The question is:  is there ( and should there, as Bergi says it is actually not a problem) a better way to reference the the property  "isRepositionable" then by "PositionXY.isRepositionable" , like by some way of "internal" referencing ?

Comment: Sure, you can make it a private state of the object. The easiest way to do this is to build the public methods in some `init` function, creating a closure over local variables instead of using the fields. It's a commonly used pattern in modern Javascript.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.isRepositionable`?

Comment: @plalx `this` would refer to the DIV the event was triggerend on

Comment: @Luaan: I've seen these `init` solutions, but I don't see how to implement them in this situation. Perhaps you could sketch it, or point to a similar question ?

Comment: @oysterhoys That's because of the way you are binding your handlers. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `this` within the functions, but you would have to make sure to properly `bind` the event handlers:

```
 var elm = document.getElementById("x");
 elm.onmousedown = PositionXY.detectBasePosition.bind(PositionXY);
 elm.onmousemove = PositionXY.startPositionAdjustment.bind(PositionXY);
 elm.onmouseup = PositionXY.stopPositionAdjustment.bind(PositionXY);
```

However, the only advantage you gain here by using `this` is the ability to re-alias `PositionXY` to some other variable while changing the initial value of `PositionXY`, which will probably never occur.

Using an IIFE, you can also overcome that issue while keeping your initial design's simplicity:

```
var YourObject = (function () {
    var YourObject = {
        someProperty: 'test',
        someFunction: function () {
            console.log(YourObject.someProperty);
        }
    };

    return YourObject;
})();
```

Comment: That constructor is not even necessary if the object should stay a singleton, but a module IEFE would fit just as well.

Comment: @Bergi No the constructor is not necessary but I use it as an IIFE here. Otherwise you would achieve the same... `PositionXY = (function () { var o = { fn: function () {//use o} };  return o; })();`

Comment: oh I see now, you're overwriting the constructor with an instance. But notice that [abusing `new` for IEFEs is an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Right, there would be constructor leakage with that approach. While responding to your comment I realized that using an IIFE without using `this` is in fact a much better approach in this case.

Comment: Thanx Guys, as a JS OOP newbee this gives me some food for thought.