# javascript correct way to self-reference variables of a function during initialization

Tags: javascript, variables, initialization, self-reference

The following works and does what I need.  However, is there a better way to reference "a" and "b" in "c:"?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bar;

        function Foo() {}
        Foo.prototype = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: function() {
                return Foo.prototype.a + Foo.prototype.b;
            }
        }

        bar = new Foo();

        console.log('c is: ' + bar.c());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="document.write('c is: ' + bar.c())">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I always do `this.a` and `this.b`

Comment: Also, idk if it matters, but you might want to use an extend() or mixin() method if you have one handy instead of clobbering Foo.prototype with a new object.

Comment: So, what do you need? How should it work with inheritance? Why do you put data properties on the prototype at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572)

Comment: Seems I screwed up this question.  The problem was when the function was being instantiated as an anonymous function. In that case, "this" isn't defined. Thanks all but closing this out.

Comment: Don't use `Foo.prototype = {/* whatever */}`, extend prototype by assignment. This way you kill default `prototype` created by engine along with the non-enumerable `constructor` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
c: function() {
  return this.a + this.b;
}
```

Comment: This is not equal... (function(){return this.a + this.b;}).call({a:4, b:5}) = 9, (function(){return Foo.prototype.a + Foo.prototype.b;}).call({a:4, b:5}) = 3... it depends on how you want to use Foo.prototype.c down the road...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new object of Foo, the properties in the constructor function and the ones added through the prototype can be access, in the objects context scope with the `this` word.

```
(function() {
    var bar;

    function Foo() {
        //Constructor function properties and methods
    }

    //Protoytpe methods and properties
    Foo.prototype = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: function() {
            return this.a + this.b;
        }
    }

    bar = new Foo();
    console.log('c is: ' + bar.c());

})();
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5773v0md/)

For more info on how the prototype works, check this out:
[How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)