# (Revealing) Module Pattern, public variables and return-statement

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to understand how *public` properties* in the **(Revealing) Module Pattern** work. An advantage pointed out by [Carl Danley "*The Revealing Module Pattern*"](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/) is:

> Explicitly defined public methods and variables which lead to increased readability

Let's take a look at this code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z775e527/)):

```
var a = function() {
    var _private = null;
    var _public = null;
    function init() {
        _private = 'private';
        _public = 'public';
    }
    function getPrivate() {
        return _private;
    }
    return {
        _public : _public,
        init : init,
        getPrivate : getPrivate,
    }
}();

a.init();
console.log( a._public ); // null
console.log( a.getPrivate() ); // "private"
```

It returns `null` when calling `a._public`. I now can manipulate that public property, like `a._public = 'public';`. But I can't change it from within my object. Or at least those changes aren't passed through. I was kinda expecting it to be `"public"` as it was updated by the `init`-method before.

Does this actually mean, that I can't have any methods, that handle *public* properties? Then *public* properties in this pattern make little sense, right? I also tried this without luck ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owztvv5m/)):

```
return {
    _pubic : _public,
    init2 : function() {
        _public = 'public';
    }
}
```

---

Last, but not least, I have a question regarding the whole `return` statement. Why isn't it possible to just use `return this;` to make everything public? As `this` should be the context of the self-invoked function, shouldn't it just return eveyrthing in it? Why do I have to create another object, that is returned? In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xusznnw6/) it returns the `window` object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this actually mean, that I can't have any methods, that handle public properties?

No, it means that you cannot have public *variables*. `var _public` is a variable, and it is not accessible from outside, and when you modify the private variable this will not be reflected in your public `._public` property.

If you want to make things public, use properties:

```
var a = function() {
    var _private = null;
    function init() {
        _private = 'private';
        this._public = 'public';
    }
    function getPrivate() {
        return _private;
    }
    return {
        _public : null,
        init : init,
        getPrivate : getPrivate,
    }
}();
```

> I can manipulate that public property, like a._public = 'public';. But I can't change it from within my object.

You can use `this` in the methods of your object, as shown above. Or you use `a` to reference the object, or possibly even store a local reference to the object you return. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this) for the differences.

> Or at least those changes aren't passed through

Yes, because variables are different from properties (unlike in some other languages like Java, and with exceptions for global ones). When you export `public: _public` in your object literal, it takes only the current value from the `_public` variable and creates a property on the object with it. There is no persistent reference to the variable, and changes to one are not reflected in the other.

> Why isn't it possible to just use `return this;` to make everything public? As this should be the context of the self-invoked function, shouldn't it just return eveyrthing in it?

Variables are part of a *scope* in JavaScript. (Except for the global one) those scopes are not objects accessible to the language.

The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) does not refer to this scope of the function, but to the context that was provided by the call. That can be the base reference in a method call, the new instance in a constructor invocation, or just nothing in a basic function call like yours (or the global `window` object in loose mode).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for your confidence :-) Actually I went for lunch right after posting this stub, seeing that you already had answered… Unfortunately you have deleted your answer, and its content is not even preserved in the history :-/

Comment: Yeah, I saw his answer too and it had some nice insights as well. But suddenly it was gone.

Answer (score 6):

In your module definition, `_public` is copied by value, because in javascript, *only objects are assigned by reference*. After that it has no link to the local _public variable whatsoever. This would therefore only work if you either "box" the _public in an object, so it gets copied by reference, or you refer to the object's property within your module as well, having only one reference to the local variable:

```
var a = function() {
    var module = {
        _public: null
    };

    // use module._public here 

    return module;
}();

a._public = "foo";
```

Comment: Seems like a cool trick to *box* things into objects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construction for creating new class

```
function a(){
    var _private = null;
    this.public = null;
    this.getPrivate = function(){
        return _private;
    };

    function init(){
        _private  = "private";
        this.public = "public";
    }

    init.apply(this, arguments);
}

//static function
a.create = function(){
    return new a();
};

//using
var b = new a();
//or
var b = a.create();
```