# How to reference internally in javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to this and can't figure this out. I have this simplified piece of code:

```
var StpTable = function () {

  function setupPager() {
    ...
    if(i<StpTable.a) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  };

  return {

    "a": 10,

    "init": function() {
      setupPager();
    }
  }

}();
```

How do I from with the `setupPager()` function reference the variable `a` without having to use the variable name `StpTable`. Tried with this.a but the scope is off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with using `StpTable`?

Comment: That's a good question. It works! It is not pretty - in my eyes - using the external name in an internal reference. But maybe it's my head that's twisted. This is new to me in javascript :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the object to a local variable before you return it and use that.

```
var StpTable = function () {

  function setupPager() {
    ...
    if(i<obj.a) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  };

  var obj = {

    "a": 10,

    "init": function() {
      setupPager();
    }
  };

  return obj;

}();
```

Or simply assign the function as property of the object:

```
var StpTable = function () {

  function setupPager() {
    ...
    if(i<this.a) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  };

  return {

    "a": 10,

    "init": setupPager,
  };

}();
```

Then `this.a` will work, assuming the function is called with `StpTable.init();`.

Comment: This. See also [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) for a comparison of the two approaches.

Comment: Alternative 3: pass `this` or `this.a` as a parameter to `setupPager`

Comment: The `obj` idea is good. It works like a charm. I like it.
My `init` function does several other things in my real code so the 2nd alternative becomes a little more complicated. 
The 3rd is also not so easy in the real code. I have several of these vars that I want to reference from within the object, so the first one is clean and simple to me. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `a` could be a local variable

```
var StpTable = function () {
  var a = 10;
  function setupPager() {
    ...
    if(i<a) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  };

  return {

    "a": a,

    "init": function() {
      setupPager();
    }
  }

}();
```