# Store prototype function in variable

Tags: javascript, prototype

My question is pretty straight forward, but I can't find an answer anywhere (maybe my search terminology isn't correct, but here goes)...

Why is it that I can do the following:

```
var _Class = function(){
    this.output = "Hello";
}

var Class = new _Class();

Class.Talk = function(){
    console.log(this.output);
}
Class.Talk(); // outputs "Hello"
```

And this:

```
var func = function(){
    console.log(Class.output);
}
func(); // outputs "Hello"
```

However I can't do:

```
var _Class = function(){
    this.output = "Hello";
}

var Class = new _Class();

Class.Talk = function(){
    console.log(this.output);
}

var func = Class.Talk;
func(); // undefined
```

I thought that this is meant to store a reference to the original function?

Comment: `Class.talk` will only exist for that instance. use `_Class.prototype.$x` to get it be around for all instances of `_Class`

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to in `func()`? It seems you should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this .

Comment: You've been waiting for that huh @self!

Comment: @FelixKling I was expecting to have created a pointer to the class?

Comment: @JordanHendrix not sure what you mean

Comment: When you call a function as `f()`, then `this` refers to the global object or `undefined`. "Methods" are not automatically bound.

Comment: @FelixKling So there is no level of inheritance / polymorphic principles in JS?

Comment: Why are you asking about prototype functions in the title but not using any in your code?

Comment: Sure there is. But you are calling the function "incorrectly". You are not calling the function as a method of an object. See the MDN documentation about `this`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I see. Interesting.

Comment: `this` is determined at execution unless you're using the arrow functions, which is a lexical `this`. Since you have removed the implicit binding of the method from its object, `this` points to the global object. There is no `output` property on the global object, hence `undefined` is returned.

Comment: @Bergi I thought that this was a valid way of defining prototypes? Or were you referring to the Talk function specifically ?

Comment: @Zze: Nope, you didn't use prototypes. `_Class` is a *constructor* if that is what you mean. To use the prototype, you'd have written `_Class.prototype.Talk = function(){…}`

Comment: @Zze: And btw, you really shouldn't name that variable "Class" when it's an instance. Which also should be lowercased (only constructor names are capitalised).

Comment: @Bergi Ass, I think I have used the wrong terminology here (apologies all). Normally I wouldn't, but the actual class I have I use it as if it were a static class, and only gets instantiated the once.

Comment: @Zze: In that case, drop the class/constructor and use an object literal instead. Also [you don't need to use `this` at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10711164/1048572).

Comment: Damn it @Bergi ... That link has just made me want to re-write thousands of lines of code. You have been incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do `func.apply(Class)` it will work because you're telling it to use the context of `Class`. The context of the function body when you do the assignment is `window`, so that's why you're seeing `undefined`

Comment: But `Class.Talk` should log something to the console, not `undefined`.

Comment: See my edit, i miss read the question. Would appreciate taking back the down vote

Comment: This is a very interesting solution I did not know you could do this!