# Why does my ES6 (using Babel) class say `this` is undefined in an instance method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, hapi.js

I am building an application in Node using Hapi.JS.

I have a class for an authentication plugin that is giving me all sorts of problems. When I attempt to reference `this` from within a method on the class, I get an error saying that `this` is undefined. Why is this happening?

An excerpt:

```
class OAuth {

  constructor () {}

  register (server, err, next) {
    this.server = server;
    this.registerRoutes();
  }

  registerRoutes () {
    console.log(this.server.route);
    this.server.route([
      {
          method: 'POST',
          path: '/oauth/token',
          config: {
              auth: false,
              handler: function(request,reply){
                console.log("test");
                reply("test");
              }
            }
      },
      {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/test',
        config: {
          auth: false,
          handler: function(request,reply){
            console.log("test");
            reply("test");
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
  }
}
module.exports = new OAuth();
```

Elsewhere this is being called like:

```
const oauth = require('./oauth');
oauth.register(server);
```

Every time the register function is called, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'server' of undefined
```

Why on earth is my instance not working?

Comment: Does console.log(this); output anything of interest?  Try that log in the constructor as well just cause?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: No it does not.

Comment: Is `oauth.register(server);` the only place where you call this method?

Comment: You never should use a `class` and export a singleton "module object". Either export the class itself, or use an object literal instead.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, that is the only call to `register`

Comment: I attempted to export the singleton as a result of this issue. Even when I export the class an instantiate it elsewhere, the problem remains

Comment: @Bergi While it's a better practice I don't see why this wouldn't work. The fact that `this` would be `undefined` is even more odd.

Comment: @Brennan I tested your class on `https://babeljs.io/` and it works just fine. It seems that there is a bug in your js engine or something like that... You should really try to debug by putting break-points if you have an IDE that supports it.

Comment: Have you tried binding the `registerRoutes` to `this`?

Comment: @plalx: The recommendation about the exports was unrelated to `this` issue (that's why it's a comment not an answer). Of course, exporting a single object would allow to directly [refer to a variable instead of `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572), but that's only a workaround.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ES6 class with babel doesn't autobind `this` for you. This is a common misconception since `class` was introduced. There are multiple ways to solve it.

1. Use ES7. Babel has an experimental (as of this post) [class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin.

   ```
   class OAuth {
     constructor () {}

     register = (server, err, next) => {
       this.server = server
       this.registerRoutes()
     }

     registerRoutes = () => {}
   }
   ```

How does this work? When you use arrow-functions along with the class-properties plugin, it gets transformed to something like the following, binding this as you expect when you use `class` syntax.

```
var OAuth = function OAuth() {
  var _this = this;

  _classCallCheck(this, OAuth);

  this.register = function (server, err, next) {
    _this.server = server;
    _this.registerRoutes();
  };

  this.registerRoutes = function () {};
}
```

2. Bind your class properties in the constructor

   ```
   class OAuth {
     constructor () {
       // `this` is the OAuth instance in the constructor
       this.register = this.register.bind(this)
       this.registerRoutes = this.registerRoutes.bind(this)
     }

     register (server, err, next) {
       // `this` is the global object.. NOT! 
       // after binding in the constructor, it's the OAuth instance ^_^
       // provided you use `new` to initialize your instance
       this.server = server
       this.registerRoutes()
     }

     registerRoutes () {}
   }
   ```
3. Use `createClass` from react, which does the binding for you. Note we're only using react for its class property binding magic. We are not creating react components.

   ```
   import React from 'react'

   const OAuth = React.createClass({
     register (server, err, next) {
       this.server = server
       this.registerRoutes()
     }

     registerRoutes () {}
   })
   ```
4. Use only `autoBind` from [react-class](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-class). Here we're making a react component using ES6+ class syntax just to use the `autoBind` method. We don't have to use `componentWillMount`, `render`, etc, which are provided with react components.

   ```
   import { autoBind } from 'react-class'

   class OAuth extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       autoBind(this)
     }

     register (server, err, next) {
       this.server = server
       this.registerRoutes()
     }

     registerRoutes () {}
   }
   ```
5. Roll your own class property binder. It's a nice exercise, basically the same as option 2, possibly less code as well.

   ```
   // call it in your constructor
   bindStuff(this, ['register', 'registerRoutes', 'etc'])

   // define it somewhere as
   function bindStuff (context, props) {
     props.forEach(prop => {
       context[prop] = context[prop].bind(context);
     })
   }
   ```
6. If you actually want to create react components, you can combine arrow-functions and property initializers to do something like

   ```
   class OAuthComponent extends React.Component {
     whateverMethodYouWant = (event) => {
       this.setState({somePropertyYouCareAbout: true}) // this is bound
     }

     anotherMethod = () => {
       this.whateverMethodYouWant() // this is bound
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I believe you can also use the "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" which doesn't require you to change anything.. Such a stupid class implementation though