# Access properties in node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node module exported like this

```
module.exports = {
 port:8080,
 server:function(){
  console.log(port);
},
}
```

I want to read the port value ( and some other values as well) inside the server function but when I run my code it returns undefined.

How can I access other properties inside my server.

Comment: `module.exports.port` or `this.port` as long as the `server` function is always called correctly (`var m = require('my-module'); m.server()` vs. passing `m.server` to some other function).

Comment: Yes, [refer to it as a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this), not like a local variable