# How to also access variable "this" inside event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

```
<div id="menu">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to access the `this` that refers to `thing` rather than the `this` that refers to the div that was clicked on, inside the event handler method `handleClick`?

**Note:** I need to access both `this`s inside `handleClick`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var thing = {
        menu: $("#menu"),

        init: function() {
            var _this = this;
            this.doSomething();
            this.menu.on("click", "div", this.handleClick);
        },

        doSomething: function() {
            console.log(this); // thing
        },

        handleClick: function() {
            console.log(this); // div that was clicked on
            // How to console.log(_this) i.e. thing ?
        }
    };
    thing.init();
});
```

Comment: Of course, in your setup you could [simply refer to it using `thing` instead of `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10711164/1048572) or `_this` or something like that

Comment: And to get access to the clicked div, you could also use [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) - so no `this` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is to wrap it and turn that `_this` variable into something used in a closure:

```
this.menu.on("click", "div", function() {
  _this.handleClick();
});
```

Now it's bound correctly to the original `this`.

You probably want to add an argument to capture what was clicked:

```
this.menu.on("click", "div", function(ev) {
  _this.handleClick(ev, this);
});
```

Then ensure your method receives this:

```
handleClick: function(ev, target) {
  // ev = Event generated
  // target = The target clicked
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest thing I've seen all day, without unnecessarily getting further confused by `this`!

Comment: Yes, this works, but this is a sloppy hack and is very bad practice. You don't need to rewrite all your class code to use _this instead of this.

Comment: @Cerin This was from 2016. Things have changed.