# Accessing properties from within Object.create(obj,props) props definition object

Tags: javascript, scope, this, javascript-objects

I'm following a [page object pattern for use with WebDriver JS](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html) based automation code. The tutorial called for a page object that looks something like what's below using [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create an object that extends a simple Page object -- but their example didn't cover having functions that referenced `this` from inside the created object. I've tried changing the the object param `get` and `value` around a couple different ways in the property configuration and haven't noticed a difference so far.

**page.js:**

```
"use strict";

function Page() {

}

Page.prototype.open = function(path) {
    browser.url('/' + path);
};

Page.prototype.getUrl = function() {
    return browser.getUrl();
};

module.exports = new Page();
```

**login.page.js:**

```
"use strict";

var Page = require('./page');

var LoginPage = Object.create(Page, {
    email:          { value: 'input#email' } ,
    password:       { value: 'input#password' } ,
    loginButton:    { value: 'button#login-button' },
    errorText:      { value: 'span.help-block' },

    loginErrorMessage: { value: 'These credentials do not match our records.' },

    open: { value: function() {
        Page.open('login');
    }},

    loginAsTestUser: { value: function() {
        this.open(); 
        browser.logger.info('Logging in');
        this.login('test@dev.com', 'test');
    }},

    login: { value: function(email, password) {
        browser.element(this.email).setValue(email);
        browser.element(this.password).setValue(password);
        browser.element(this.loginButton).click();
    }}
});

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

**test.spec.js**

```
"use strict";

var LoginPage = require('../pages/login.page.js');
var Header = require('../pages/header.page.js');

describe('Navigation bar', function() {
    before('open login page', LoginPage.open);

    it('should be visible', function() {
        browser.isVisibleWithinViewport(Header.navbar).should.be.true;
    });

    describe('when logged in', function() {
        before('login', LoginPage.loginAsTestUser);

        it('should have the Add dropdown list displayed', function() {
            browser.isVisibleWithinViewport(Header.addDropdownButton).should.be.true;
        });

        after('logout', Header.logout);
    });
});
```

Here's the error for `this.open`:

```
1) Navigation bar when logged in "before all" hook:
this.open is not a function
running chrome
TypeError: this.open is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (/code/tests/test/pages/login.page.js:20:18)
    at Promise.F (/code/tests/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:35:28)
```

And when `this.open();` is replaced with its function to let the code progress, `this.login();` errors as well:

```
1) Navigation bar when logged in "before all" hook:
this.login is not a function
running chrome
TypeError: this.login is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous> (/code/tests/test/pages/login.page.js:24:18)
    at Promise.F (/code/tests/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:35:28)
```

I guess I could see `this` not meaning much in that property config object being passed to `Object.create` but I'm not sure how else you'd do this - the [documentation for Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) doesn't even reference an example that works this way.

*Edit: This is different from the proposed duplicate question:  [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) - I am talking about referencing variable properties of an object while I'm creating it because the variables build on each other. The proposed duplicate is talking about JavaScript scope issues in general with `this` - this particular question is a lot more focused and is more about how to build properties of an object using other properties of that object before that object is fully created.*

Comment: It might be that the 'this' you're trying to access is in the local scope (the function you're calling it scope). What you would want to try is to attach your open() method to the Class's scope.

Comment: What is `Page` here?

Comment: How are you calling `loginAsTestUser`. The value of `this` depends almost entirely on how a function is called, not on how it is defined.

Comment: I'll update the example, one moment

Comment: The example is updated, thanks.

Comment: @anjunatl What is `Page` though? A constructor? Plain object?

Comment: @AndrewLi As I understand it, it's a plain object. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Adrián Do you mean like this - https://hastebin.com/izasikofag.js ? It works, but the code is a lot more verbose now. Is that the only way there is to access those more internal properties and methods?

Comment: Did you get that `page.js` from the tutorial (that you forgot to link)? `module.exports = new Page` is horribly misguided.

Comment: @Bergi I'll find the link, thanks for catching that

Comment: I had the wrong spec example in place, it wasn't calling `LoginPage.loginAsTestUser` - thanks @slebetman - it's updated now

Comment: @Bergi The post is updated - it's http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html

Comment: Yes, `before('login', LoginPage.loginAsTestUser);` is the culprit. You need to bind the method to the instance (see the duplicate) or [not use `this` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572) which might work better in your singleton scenario

Comment: @Bergi While I understand how this is conceptually a duplicate question, the solution related to `Object.create` / `Object.defineProperties` doesn't appear to be covered in the linked question.

Comment: @Bergi re: a solution that doesn't use this, would that be like this? Thanks https://hastebin.com/izasikofag.js - It's verbose as far as writing out the code goes, but I bet the `{ value: foo }` assignments could be automated through a function, so it might not be so bad.

Comment: @anjunatl That doesn't really matter. As you said, the concept is the same. The same principle applies, it doesn't matter how you created the object.

Comment: @anjunatl The solution is not related to `Object.create`/`Object.defineProperties` at all, that's why it doesn't matter

Comment: @anjunatl You could just refer to `LoginPage.…` statically instead of `this.…`. Although your solution with the scoped variables works just as well. Oh, and since you refer to `Page.open` instead of `this.open`, you actually don't need `Object.create` inheritance at all. Just return an object literal.

Comment: @Bergi Took a min to make sure I had the test correct, but referring to `LoginPage.foo` worked. I thought about trying that earlier today, I don't know why I didn't think that'd work. Next time I'll just try it anyway & see if I surprise myself. Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi If you'd like to post that as the answer, I'll accept it