# Use arrow function as method passed to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, this

I have an object with a method that will be passed to requestAnimationFrame.
At the moment I create the object than reassign the method with an arrow function it returns.

```
var player={fn:function(){return ()=>{game.circle(this.x,this.y,this.radius)}},
x:200,y:300,radius:20};
player.fn=player.fn();
```

Can this be done without the reassigning the method after creating the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just [use a static reference to `player` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572):

```
const player = {
  fn() {
    game.circle(player.x, player.y, player.radius);
  },
  x:200,
  y:300,
  radius:20
};
requestAnimationFrame(player.fn);
```

But no, otherwise there's no way to write this without a separate assignment. Usually you however would just [`bind` or use the arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) when calling `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
var player = {
  fn() {
    game.circle(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
  },
  x:200,
  y:300,
  radius:20
};
requestAnimationFrame(() => player.fn());
```

Comment: Although your answer would work I'm passing the method to request animation frame in a way that it wouldn't work however your link to bind should work fine thank you

Comment: @user7951676 Well you haven't shown that part of your code in the question, so I can't advise on it