# Compare these simple javascript code related to object

Tags: javascript

I have written this code can anyone tell what I have written is correct or not.

```
var employee = {
  name: "John Smith",
  job: "Programmer",
  age: 31,
  printing: function(){
    for (just in employee){
        alert(this.emloyee(just)"is"this.employee[just])
    }

  }

}
```

And tell me that the upper code can work the same.

```
var employee = {
  name: "John Smith",
  job: "Programmer",
  age: 31,
  showAlert: function(){
    alert("Name is " + this.name);
    alert("Job is " + this.job);
    alert("Age is " + this.age);
  }
}

employee.showAlert()
```

Comment: this.emloyee(just) looks like a typo, so it is probably not correct. But in general, it helps to start with what your expectations of the code are. It is difficult for an outsider to judge whether code makes sense unless you know what it should do. If you are asking about code reviews, stackoverflow is not a good place to ask. Those questions tend to be closed quickly.

Comment: `alert(this.emloyee(just)"is"this.employee[just])` is a syntax error. Did you mean to concatenate the strings? Use the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for

```js
var employee = {
  name: "John Smith",
  job: "Programmer",
  age: 31,
  showAlert() {
    for (const just in this) {
      if (typeof this[just] != "function") {
        alert(just + " is " + this[just])
      }
    }
  },
};
employee.showAlert()
```

Notice the `const` declaration in the loop, the usage of the property name `just` instead of `employee(just)`, the string concatenation with `+`, and the [use of `this` instead of `employee`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this).

Also the `showAlert` method itself is just a property that gets enumerated by the `for … in` loop, so I added a condition to only alert non-function properties.