# How to access class attributes and functions within modules properly

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, module

I'm writing classes in ES6 modules using object literals and I want to set object attributes within a function. Now I know modules are executed in strict mode by default which makes usage of `this` safe or at least safer, but I'm not sure whether `foo()` modifies the object I'm accessing in the 'parent' script file or just the local object existing only in `Controller.mjs`. Do both function calls have the same effect?

```
//Controller.mjs
const Controller = {
    someAttr1: [],
    someAttr2: true,

    foo: function () {
        this.someAttr1.push("some value");
        Controller.someAttr1.push("some value");
    }
};

//export Controller's interface...

//SomeOtherFile.mjs
import { Controller } from 'Controller.mjs'

Controller.foo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the object I'm accessing in the 'parent' script file or just the local object existing only in *Controller.mjs*

There is only a single object in your code. The `import` declaration really does nothing but create an alias for the `const Controller` variable in the imported module. There is no second object getting instantiated.

In general, for using `this` vs `Controller` to refer to the object, see [Javascript: Object Literal reference in own key's function instead of 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572). It doesn't matter whether the code is spread across modules or not for that.