# Use Async functions who call other functions from the same module.exports in Javascript and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

i trying to make an apps who can read a JSON with NodeJs.

What i did get good result ( perhaps slow to execute. )
I would like an expert view who can take a look on my code, cause i feel lost and confuse ...

Actually : 
**killboard.js** using bent for JSON

```
const bent = require('bent');
const getJSON = bent('json');
const config = require('../config.json');

function showKill(kill)
{
    console.log(kill.Killer.Name + " est un meurtrier !");
}

function getKill(killsList) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        killsList.some(function(kill, index) {
            console.log("One kill ...");
            showKill(kill);
        });
    });

}



module.exports = {
    exec: async() =>
    {
        let killsList = await getJSON('https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/events?limit=51&offset=0');
        await getKill(killsList);
    }

}
```

And my APP :

```
const KillBoar = require('./module/killboard');

KillBoar.exec();
```

It works fine ....

But how can i integrate : showKill and getKill canonically inside the "module.exports".
I mean something like  that :

```
module.exports = {
    exec: async() =>
    {
        let killsList = await getJSON('https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/events?limit=51&offset=0');
        await getKill(killsList);
    },
    getKill(killsList) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            killsList.some(function(kill, index) {
                console.log("One kill ...");
                showKill(kill);
            });
        });

    },
    showKill(kill)
    {
        console.log(kill.Killer.Name + " est un meurtrier !");
    }

}
```

Cause if i do, i have this error :

```
(node:7392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: getKill is not defined
    at Object.exec (C:\Users\Baptiste\Desktop\BotDiscord\KillBoard\module\killboard.js:26:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:7392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which 
was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thank you to take time to answer !

Comment: No, it doesn't really work. The promise returned by `getKill` is never resolved. And actually, that function should not return a promise at all - it does nothing asynchronous.

Comment: Uh, why do both of your snippets define two separate `getKill` functions/methods?

Comment: It is a mistake copy/past

Comment: so what is the correct way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You changed them from function definitions (that are called as plain functions) to methods of the `module.exports` object, so you now need to call them as methods on that:

```
module.exports.getKill(killsList);
…
module.exports.showKill(kill);
```

Alternatively, you might get away with `this.getKill(…)`/`this.showKill(…)`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711164/1048572) for details on the difference.

A third alternative would be to keep them as functions, and just add them to the export. Then you could call them either way:

```
function showKill(kill) { … }

module.exports = {
    async execc() { … },
    showKill,
};
```

Comment: I see. 

So what is the best way to do what i want  .? the most "academec" and clean

Comment: @BaptisteBauer The most clean and academic way would be to switch to ES6 module declarations, and just use named `export`s. Otherwise, using `this` and methods is probably most common.