# Referencing this or instance in javascript singleton

Tags: javascript

I was dabbling with singletons and extending classes and came up with this 'working' code.

```
let instance = null;

class Motorcycle {
    constructor(engine, color) {
        if(!instance) {
            this.engine = engine;
            this.color = color;
            instance = this;
        } else {
            return instance;
        }

    }
}

class Car extends Motorcycle {
    constructor(engine, color) {
        if(!instance) {
            super(engine, color);
            this.doors = 4;
        } else {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}

class SUV extends Car {
    constructor(engine, color, doors) {
        if(!instance) {
            super(engine,color);
            instance.doors = doors == undefined ? 5 : doors;
        } else {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I realized that in the constructor for sub-classes I can set doors with `instance.doors` and  `this.doors`.

So I have two questions:

1. Does it matter enough to have a best practice?
2. What is that best practice?

Comment: At some point you might want to have two cars without having to refactor the whole thing. Concerning 2.: Singletons are a bad practice, use objects.

Comment: I tested it trivially, but what this does is only the first one gets created. So if you create an SUV first, that is the instance. So there shouldn't be two singletons. Just two different options for what that singleton might be. Another problem, but this was just for fun.

Comment: Your `Car` and `Motorcycle` should extend or "implement" (not really  thing in vanilla JS) a `Vehicle` class.

Comment: What compels this in the first place? For the extra complexity, ,what were you hoping to gain?

Comment: Thank you both for your thoughts. I know the problem statement is ridiculous. I was playing with the edge of my knowledge. I just wanted to know what it would look like to mix singletons in a class hierarchy and made one up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it matter enough to have a best practice?

Not in your case probably, [but there is a difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this).

> What is that best practice?

Do not use singletons. Especially not when subclassing. Your code is unable to create an instance of a separate subclass, is unable to create multiple cars, is unable to create a `new SUV` after creating a `new Car` (and also a `Car` is not a `MotorCycle`).

Comment: Thank you. It hadn't occurred to me that one is an object literal.

Comment: @CryptoRAT No, it's not an object literal, but the question of using `this` vs `instance` to refer to the object is exactly the same.

Comment: My understanding from the article is that ```instance``` is the object literal in the global scope of this tiny code fragment. ```this``` in another context, not my example code, is so much more. That is why for my problem it doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton objects should exist outside the constructor; preferably inside a map and accessed by their class name. Constructors should really only call their super constructor or set instance variables.

You will also need a way to dynamically bind constructor arguments, this is taken care of in the `ctorBind` function below.

You could also call `getSingleton(SUV)` a second time without `args`. This example just shows that the original `SUV` was not modified upon returning.

```js
// REFLECTION UTILS
const getClassName = (obj) => obj.toString().match(/ (\w+)/)[1]
const ctorBind = (ctor, args) => new (ctor.bind.apply(ctor, [null].concat(args)))()

// MAIN FUNCTION
const main = () => {
  console.log(getSingleton(SUV, 'V6', 'Red', 5))
  console.log(getSingleton(SUV, 'V8', 'Blue', 6)) // Not updated...
}

// BEGIN SINGLETON MAP AND LOOKUP
const vehicleSingletons = {};
function getSingleton(vehicleClass, ...args) {
  const className = getClassName(vehicleClass)
  if (vehicleSingletons[className] == null) {
    vehicleSingletons[className] = ctorBind(vehicleClass, args);
  }
  return vehicleSingletons[className];
}

// BEGIN CLASS DEFINITIONS
class Vehicle {
  constructor(engine, color) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
  constructor(engine, color) {
    super(engine, color);
  }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  constructor(engine, color, doors) {
    super(engine, color);
    this.doors = doors;
  }
}

class SUV extends Car {
  constructor(engine, color, doors) {
    super(engine, color, doors);
  }
}

main()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: `getClassName(vehicleClass)` should be just `vehicleClass.name`, and `ctorBind(vehicleClass, args)` should be just `new vehicleClass(...args)`. (Btw it doesn't *bind* the constructor, it just calls it)

Comment: You are getting a singleton each vehicle type. I was exploring, for fun, how to get only one vehicle type. So if you create an SUV first then it can not become a Car or Motorcycle. I'm sorry I have no logical scenario to which to apply it, I just followed my curiosity.