# How do I access the object properties from other properties, while within a method using the 'this' keyword?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const america = {
  name: 'United State of America',
  yearFounded: 1776,
  details: {
    symbol: 'eagle',
    currency: 'USD',
    printDetails: function() {
      console.log(`The ${this.name} was founded in ${this.yearFounded} and its currency is ${this.currency}, with an ${this.symbol} symbol`);
    }
  }
}

america.details.printDetails();
```

Comment: You can use `console.log(`The ${this.name} was founded in ${this.yearFounded} and its currency is ${this.details.currency}, with an ${this.details.symbol} symbol`
      );` and call the method as `america.details.printDetails.call(america);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name and the founding year are not part of the object on which you are calling the method, but some other object. You can access it [by explicitly referring to `america.…`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711064/javascript-object-literal-reference-in-own-keys-function-instead-of-this), there is no way to access it through the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). The `this` value in your method call refers to the `details` object only.

Alternatively, move the `printDetails` method to the outer object (so that you can call `america.printDetails()` instead of `america.details.print()`), and use `this.name` and `this.details.currency` respectively. Or just flatten the entire structure into a single object.

Comment: Thanks big time Bergi. Accessing it by explicitly referring to america helped. const america = {
  name: 'United State of America',
  yearFounded: 1776,
  details: {
    symbol: 'eagle',
    currency: 'USD',
    printDetails: function() {
      console.log(`The ${america.name} was founded in ${america.yearFounded} and its currency is ${this.currency}, with an ${this.symbol} symbol`);
    }
  }
}